# Error when try to replace bracket character "(" or ")" in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace character "(" and ")" in my data frame with space, but got an error:

```
error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 1
```

Here is my code:

```
df['ytest']=df['ytest'].str.replace("(","")
df['ytest']=df['ytest'].str.replace(")","")
```

Here is the example of the dataframe:

```
| ytest                                                       |
|=============================================================|
|('pasal xx tahun 2002',)                                     |
|('pasal 1 tahun 2009', 'pasal 2 2012', 'pasal 4', 'pasal 8') |
|('pasal 1b',)                                                |
|('pasal 16', 'pasal 9')                                      |
```

Comment: Whatr version of pandas are you using ? With 1.1.5 I had no error and with latest 1.2.5 I have just that warning about the regex

Comment: it result NaN when passing regex=False . mine is version 1.1.5

Comment: Ok, you have a list of tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you just need to `join` the values:

```py
df['ytest'] = df['ytest'].str.join(', ')
```

If you want another delimiter between the individual values, replace `', '` with the value you need.

If your rows contained string data, you could use

```py
df['ytest']=df['ytest'].str.replace("[()]", "", regex=True)
```

Or, if you do not want to use a regex:

```py
df['ytest']=df['ytest'].str.replace("(", "", regex=False)
df['ytest']=df['ytest'].str.replace(")", "", regex=False)
```

From the [Pandas 1.1.5 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.5/user_guide/text.html):

> If you do want literal replacement of a string (equivalent to `str.replace()`), you can set the optional `regex` parameter to *False*, rather than escaping each character. In this case both `pat` and `repl` must be strings